# Testing characters from many languages using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

For my site I am implanting a username for my users. I was looking at Snapchat's username validation rules to guide me for some best practices and they have the following:

```
Must be 3-15 characters long
Can’t contain spaces
Must begin with a letter
Can only contain letters, numbers, and the special characters hyphen ( - ), underscore ( _ ), and period ( . ), EXCEPT that the username:
Can’t begin with a number, hyphen, underscore, or period
Can’t end with a hyphen, underscore, or period
Can’t contain emojis or other symbols such as @, $, #, etc.
Will appear only in lower-case letters within the app
```

This had me thinking how does this apply to my users who are all over the world. When a requirement such as `Must begin with a letter` how do I check with this with regex so that all letters in all languages pass, but at the same time things such as emojis or "weird" characters fail?

Comment: You'd start with `\p{L}` and go from there. What language would this be done in ? Btw, emoji's are deceptive.

Comment: Actually, to do this all in Unicode requires a rewrite of those rules to include a lot more/less characters. It seems to be mostly ascii centric (except for emoji).

Comment: Programming language ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm writing a mobile app (Java/Swift) and a Nodejs backend (Javascript). The validation to make sure the username is correct is occurring on both the frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like:

```
(?=[\p{L}\d_\-.]{3,13})^[\p{L}](?=.*?[^ ])[\p{L}\d_\-.]+[\p{L}\d]$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/53yNMP/4)